# How does gulp-sourcemaps retrieve ** matched path from src method

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

I'm using gulp to build project, together with gulp-sourcemaps for generating sourcemaps.

I have several compnents like this:

```
public
 |-- src
      |-- comp1
      |     |-- c1-a.js
      |     |-- c1-b.js
      |
      |-- comp2
            |-- c2-a.js
            |-- c2-b.js
```

I'd like to build them into following strcture:

```
public
 |-- dist
 |    |-- comp1
 |    |     |-- c1-a.min.js
 |    |     |-- c1-a.min.js.map
 |    |     |-- c1-b.min.js
 |    |     |-- c1-b.min.js.map
 |    |
 |    |-- comp2
 |          |-- c2-a.min.js
 |          |-- c2-a.min.js.map
 |          |-- c2-b.min.js
 |          |-- c2-a.min.js.map
 |
 |-- src/
```

Currently my gulp task can generate files into correct path:

```
gulp.task('component', function() {
  gulp.src('./public/src/**/*.js', {base: './public/src'})
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {
      includeContent: false,
      sourceRoot: '/src/' // here's the problem
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/dist'))
})
```

but there are two problems:

1. the `sourceRoot` in map file is not correct:
   expecting `"sourceRoot":"/src/comp1/"` but the result is `"sourceRoot":"/src/"`
2. neither does `sourceMappingURL` in compressed file:
   expecting `sourceMappingURL=c1-a.min.js.map` but the result is `sourceMappingURL=../../comp1/c1-a.min.js.map`

How can I append the `**` part to `sourceRoot` and fix sourceMappingURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sourceRoot` is getting set as `/src/` because that's what you told it here:

```
gulp.src('./public/src/**/*.js', {base: './public/src'})
```

You've set `{base: './public/src'}` so everything on down the line will treat paths relative to `src`, so that is the correct `sourceRoot`. But at the top of the mapping, it should have paths relative to those in the `"sources":[...]` part (e.g. `"sources":["comp1/c1-a.min.js.map"]`).

Nevertheless, if you really wanted to change the sourceRoot, you can do so using the [`sourceRoot` option to gulp-sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps), but then your `sources` would be wrong. However, gulp-sourcemaps version 2.0.0-alpha (which you'd have to explicitly request in your `package.json` since it's prerelease) also has a `mapSources` option to let you modify those too.

Similarly, you can use `sourceMappingURLPrefix` or `sourceMappingURL` to alter the sourceMappingURL. In the latter case, you'll get the full `file` object, so you can inspect e.g. `cwd`, `base`, etc. `console.debug` or Visual Studio Code can [be a big help](https://hansrwindhoff.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/debugging-task-runner-tasks-like-gulp-with-visual-studio-code-editordebugger/) when debugging npm/gulp tasks! That article shows how to set breakpoints, inspect variables etc. which I've found very useful.